# Coursera Python: Programming for everybody assignment 5.2

Tags: python, numbers, variable-assignment

I have been taking Coursera's course, Programming for Everybody with Python. But one of the assignment 5.2 on week 7 got my attention.

The objective is to make the user enter some numbers and enter done, when he entered all the numbers he wanted. After that, the output should be the biggest number and smallest number he entered.

Here is the problem. If I enter a negative number it is not displayed. Let's say I enter: 32, 55,10, -2 76. The output should be 76 and -2. But what really happens is that 76 and 10 are printed out.

Do you guys have any idea why this happens?

Here is the code.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        print (num)

        num = int(num)

        for number in range(num):

            if largest is None or largest < num:
                largest = num
                continue
            elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
                smallest = num       
    except ValueError:
        print("Please, enter only numbers.")

print ("Maximum", largest)
print ("Minimum", smallest)
```

Comment: What do you think `range(-2)` does?

Comment: Why are you even looping over a range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,the issue is that why are you iterating over an int if it isnt a list? 
You can rather do it with out a loop:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        print (num)
        num = int(num)
        if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest = num
        elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
             smallest = num
    except ValueError:
        print("Please, enter only numbers.")

print ("Maximum", largest)
print ("Minimum", smallest)
```

output:

```
Enter a number: 12
12
Enter a number: 56
56
Enter a number: 34
34
Enter a number: -2
-2
Enter a number: 17
17
Enter a number: done
Maximum 56
Minimum -2
```

Comment: The `continue` isn't necessary, as the only other code in that loop is the `elif` block which already won't run if the `if` executes.

Comment: True,didnt see that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was my answer. Try this. Let me know what you don't understand.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" :
            break
        num = int(num)
        if largest is None or num > largest:
            largest = num
        elif smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## This code will work for your assignment

largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
try:
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num == "done":
break
# print (num)

```
    num = int(num)

    for number in range(num):

        if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest = num
            continue
        elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
            smallest = num
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input")
```

print ("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)